# Landscape Orientation doesn't resize my UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, html, jsp, ios6

Here is the context of my problem :

I have a client application (ObjC)calling a player.jsp file located on the server (Java), to display it in my application in an UIWebView. The Java application is a web application which displays learning formations and i have to build an application to display these contents on an iPad.

The player in the web app uses **iframes** to display the content, and in my iPad application, i'm just loading this player in my UIWebView and it works, but with some sizing problems.
This player can open any type of files but I'm focusing only on HTML files.

The problem is when i switch to Landscape orientation, the content isn't resized as it should be and i can't scroll either.
When i launch the application in landscape, the size is good. Then i can switch in portrait and the resize is also done. The problem occurs only from portrait to landscape (the width is actually good but the height is too high and i can't scroll... it's not resized to the size of the launch of the app in landscape mode)
 I've been searching for an answer for couple days now, been reading that adding :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
                               maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

into the header of my HTML files would help, but it actually doesn't. It actually even does no difference at all.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, not resizing but rotation issues in general and this seemed to fix it

[iOS Orientation Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355028/ios-orientation-issues)

I know its not the best help, but it didnt solve some rotatin issues aswell as resizing!

Comment: the thing is i'm not loading an HTML file in the webview but a JSP which displays the HTML file. I can load any content with your method without any trouble but unfortunately i have to call this player.jsp because it also launches other server methods for progression feedback of the learning formations